# Checks before renaming element in Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse, resources, refactoring, rename, rcp

I'm currently writing an RCP application with custom editors. I'm trying to check if the file that is to be renamed is open in an editor. Using a custom RenameParticipant I can check this and prevent the rename operation, but this happens AFTER the user has entered a new name. I would like the check to happen before. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to obtain the editors that are opened in your RCP application. Eclipse allows you to do this by means of the following line:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences();
```

Then, you have to check whether your file is opened in one of these editors. To do this, you can iterate the resulting array. Each of the elements of the array is of type `IEditorReference`. You can get the file that is opened in each editor reference by means of the method `getEditorInput()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mario! I can use this to test whether the file is opened or not, but I need to find the correct place to do so. Using a RenameParticipant allows me to run the check after the used has entered the new name but before the file is renamed. However, I would like to run the check before the user has even been asked to enter a new name. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can create your own action and add it to the popup menu (by means of the "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus" extension point). This way you can run the check wherever you want in your code. Have a look at this: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-action-contribution/. To avoid developing the renaming functionality from scratch, you can reuse or inherit from the "RenameAction" class of the Eclipse JDT. And, by the way, according to StackOverflow policies, instead of giving "thanks" (which is greatly appreaciated :-), it is better to vote up my answer, because it gives me points :-)

Comment: This looks promising, I will take a look at it. Noted, I have upvoted your answer now ;). Still, thanks!